# Defaulting values from Burn Options page based on previous install

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

I have been working on a new Burn bootstrapper which requires a custom options page. I have gotten the page to look how it needs to and behave how it should, but need to default the values in the Options page based on the values selected in the previous install. These values are stored in INI files for the program which is installed with the bootstrapper.

I have played with storing the Burn GUI values in the registry, as I saw there is a  for Burn, but it does not seem to read the registry keys into the GUI variables (or does this after the user clicks 'install'). Is there a way to accomplish this?

An example:

Burn Variables (tie to GUI controls in the theme file)

```
<Variable Name="txtServer" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=""/> 
<Variable Name="txtDatabase" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=""/> 
<Variable Name="txtUserID" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="id"/> 
<Variable Name="txtPwd" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value="pwd"/> 

<util:RegistrySearch Id="CustCode" Variable="txtCustCode" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[WixBundleManufacturer]\[WixBundleName]" Value="CustCode"  Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="Server" Variable="txtServer" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[WixBundleManufacturer]\[WixBundleName]" Value="Server" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value"/>
<util:RegistrySearch Id="Database" Variable="txtDatabase" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[WixBundleManufacturer]\[WixBundleName]" Value="Database" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="DBID" Variable="txtUserID" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[WixBundleManufacturer]\[WixBundleName]" Value="DBID" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
<util:RegistrySearch Id="DBPWD" Variable="txtPwd" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[WixBundleManufacturer]\[WixBundleName]" Value="DBPWD" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
```

The registry values are getting read into the variables, but not showing up in the GUI/Options page. Showing this is very important so the users can see the settings the installer will be using. If at all possible, reading from the INI file instead of the registry would be much preferred.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be most helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using v3.10 or later?  [4496](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4496) was implemented in 3.10.0.1502, which added support for loading the value of a `Variable` into a textbox.

Comment: I was using v3.9.something. After updating, all of my variables are updating the options page controls except for my FolderEditBox for some reason. Also, is there any way to read from INI files instead of from the registry?

Comment: Some controls in v3 are special, something different might need to be done for FolderEditBox.  There is no IniFileSearch today.